# Events and Entity Component Systems?

Tags: c#, events, entity-component-system

What are common ways to implement Events in an entity component system ?

Most games typically have following events :

- Damage Events
- Collision Events
- Area of interest Events
- Entity Died/Respawn events
- Teleport Event/Command
- ...

How are those typically implemented into an ECS ? As "Event" Entities ? Components ? Or just regular method calls by an "Event pipeline" ?

What are the pros and cons ? What would you choose and why ?

Comment: You may be interested in [Entity interaction in a component design with events](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/138092/39518), [How does entity communication work?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1119/39518) [Event/packet-based entity component system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/157250/39518) and [How to properly implement message handling in a component based entity system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/23834/39518) or other hits for a [search on "entity component event"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=entity+component+event)

Comment: Could I ask you to review the existing answers in this search, and take some time to refine your question to a more specific problem to solve, after considering the potential implementations that have been documented here?

Comment: as I've been toying with ECS I've come to realize that the key part is not components, but systems. Events shouldn't necessarily be thought of as associated with entities or components, but with one system informing other systems that it's done system, e.g. the health system informs that a player has died, so the tournament round system can see that only one player remains, and end the round.